# Conditional replacement using perl

Tags: sed, perl

Very simple hypothetical question,

I've reached the limitation of `sed` and need to change my `sed` script to `perl`. So for `sed` conditional replacement of

```
sed '/condition/ s/xx/yy/'
```

How to do it in perl?

For e.g. how to do the following in perl?

```
seq 6 > /tmp/tf

$ paste -d '' /tmp/tf /tmp/tf | sed -E '/[135]/s/^(.)(.)$/\1.\2-/'
1.1-
22
3.3-
44
5.5-
66

$ paste -d '' /tmp/tf /tmp/tf | perl -pe 's/$&/$1.$2-/ if /^([135])(.)$/'
.-
22
.-
44
.-
66
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you aim to reduce typing and to increase the similarity between how to do this in Perl and `sed`. In that case, both `sed` and Perl allow the reuse of the most recently matched regular expression by specifying an empty expression.

```bash
sed '/^\([135]\)\(.\)$/ s//\1.\2-/'
```

```bash
perl -pe '/^([135])(.)$/ && s//$1.$2-/'
```

The empty regular expression in the `s///` command will reuse the expression from the preceding test (in general, the most recent matching expression).

In Perl, we must add `&&` between the test and the substitution to let it act as a short-circuit `if`-statement. In `sed`, the first expression simply acts as the *address* of the substitution command.

In general,

```bash
sed '/condition/ s/xx/yy/'
```

... would be "the same as" (taking slightly different syntax and regular expression flavors into account)

```bash
perl -pe '/condition/ && s/xx/yy/'
```

In this case, though, it would be simpler just to apply the substitution directly:

```bash
sed 's/^\([135]\)\(.\)$/\1.\2-/'
```

```bash
perl -pe 's/^([135])(.)$/$1.$2-/'
```

Comment: Bravo!!! This is a more comprehensive answer than the first one I chose. and I learned a new trick for sed too! I'll choose this as the answer once the vote overtakes the first one. Also, reiterate my comment on the first one, although OP uses a simple example, _"I do need to match first, then replace $1 and $2 in my real case."_ for performance concerns (if the matching first can dramatically reduce the replace operation, 0.1% vs 100%). thx!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `$1` and so on are reset on each new regular expression, so they will be empty unless you repeat them in the `s` command, i.e.

```perl
s/^([135])(.)$/$1.$2-/ if /^([135])(.)$/'
```

which can simplified by removing the `if`:

```
s/^([135])(.)$/$1.$2-/
```

In a more general case, you can preserve the captured values:

```
if (/^([135])(.)$/) { $a=$1; $b=$2; s/$&/$a.$b-/; }
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution for the more general case, as I do need to match first, then replace $1 and $2 in perl in my real case.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -pe 's/^ (<[135]>) (.) $/$0.$1-/;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -pe 's/^ (.) (.) $/$0.$1-/ if  m/^ <[135]> /;'  

#Immediately above being a re-arrangement of:

raku -pe 'if m/^ <[135]> /  {s/^ (.) (.) $/$0.$1-/};'
```

Posting this in the hopes that it will prove useful for Perl users who dabble in Raku. In Raku, capturing starts from `$0`, and character classes are created with `<[`…`]>` markers (square brackets alone are reserved for grouping). Also matching is generally insensitive to whitespace (i.e. Perl5's `\x` is the default).

Trying @Kusalananda's first Perl5 code example (with a Raku 'accent' as described) will produce the Raku error `Null regex not allowed`. Hence the first Raku answer above looks much more like @Kusalananda's *last* Perl5 code example. (The second Raku answer above utilizes an `if` conditional, which some users may find more readable).

Sample Input:

```
11
22
33
44
55
66
```

Sample Output:

```
1.1-
22
3.3-
44
5.5-
66
```

---

ADDENDUM: Since the OP posted sample data that concatenated *identical* digits--I am wondering if there is still an unanswered question here regarding ***backreferences***. In Raku if you want to reuse the first capture within a match (e.g. left side of `s///` operator), you do the following:

```perl
raku -pe 's/^ (<[135]>) $0 $/$0.$0-/;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -pe 's{^ (<[135]>) $0 $} = "$0.$0-";'
```

OR (named captures, below):

```perl
raku -pe 's/^ $<myOdd>=<[135]> $<myOdd> $/$<myOdd>.$<myOdd>-/;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -pe 's{^ $<myOdd>=<[135]> $<myOdd> $} = "$<myOdd>.$<myOdd>-";'
```

The second and fourth examples immediately above use Raku's new "substitute-assignment" notation, which (to enhance readability) also allows various delimiters--brackets, curlies, etc. (Of course, a separate `if` conditional could be used as denoted in the earlier section, but that might result in less-readable code).

https://raku.org/archive/rfc/144.html
https://raku.org/archive/rfc/331.html
https://raku.org

Comment: As I've repeatedly commented in the previous replies, although OP uses a simple example, _"I do need to match first, then replace $1 and $2 in my real case."_. As for the _identical digits_, it's all there for $1 and $2 matching. If you could give a simple example that doesn't have identical digits but still able to provide $1 and $2 matching, and requires equal or less steps in preparation than OP, I'll be glad to hear that. thx.

Comment: I've added an extra example, in classic 'pattern-action' format (third from the top). Hopefully you find it useful.

Comment: thanks, already up-voted. Hmm... I was asking for providing the sample test data, and the _"match first, then replace"_ was only the reason for that (and not the focus) though.